# Deleting a record after updating it under some condition using an SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm struggling with an unknown syntax error given by `MySQL` server when executing this query

```
CREATE TRIGGER del_entry AFTER UPDATE on some_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.col=0 THEN
    DELETE FROM some_table
    WHERE prim_key = NEW.prim_key;
  END IF;
END;
```

The sql error given is:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`,

which means the `where` clause line...

Any thought?

Comment: This error is usually given when the statement is not complete, but I double checked the `DELETE` query, it doesn't need further entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is ok, but to add the trigger, you'll need to change the delimiter so MySQL knows where the trigger ends. The normal is `;`, but since the trigger contains several, it won't add.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER del_entry AFTER UPDATE on some_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.col=0 THEN
    DELETE FROM some_table
    WHERE prim_key = NEW.prim_key;
  END IF;
END;
// 

DELIMITER ;
```

[An SQLfiddle that adds the exact trigger successfully](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3402a/1).